# Windows Form across processes - .net

Tags: .net, windows, forms, add-in

What is the best way to not opening a form if it is already opened from another process in .net.

For ex: We are having an Add-in application which can be hosted via multiple office applications. [Word, Excel, powerpoint]
If a form is already opened from one of the host., how do I stop opening it again from another process?

Comment: Update your question with details about how you are managing user session.

Comment: Nothing simple, the tall wall that the OS puts between processes to isolate their memory usage is very difficult to scale.  Especially when you have no real idea what process that might be and the process is not a .NET process.  You'd need a dedicated process that acts as an arbiter, one that the add-ins connect to with, say, a named pipe.  Lots of "don't do it!" concerns there, you only get decent help when you explain why this is a problem.

Comment: Thanks for this response Hans. The problems is if a user has multiple add-in sessions opened through different processes for example - 2 WORD instances., 2 Excel Instances and 2 Power Point instances.., when the session gets timed out, the user getting prompt for 6 times which is actually an real embarrassment. We are trying to see if there could be a way to handle the situation.